# Automatically add an object to a vector of that objects parent

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am designing a game engine in c++. I am currently working on categorizing the different entities in the game. My base class is SpriteObject that two classes MovableObject and FixedObject inherit from. Now if i for example create an instance of a MovableObject and want to add it to a Vector of Sprite and a Vector of MovableObject i just do:

```
Vector<Sprite*> sprites;
Vector<MovableObject*> movableObjects;
MovableObject* movingObject = new MovableObject();
sprites.push_back(movingObject);
movableObjects.push_back(movingObject);
```

But as the different categories and entities grow the code will get large (and it would get tiresome to add every entity to every vector that it belongs to). How do i automatically add an object to the vector that it belongs to when it is created?

EDIT 1: I think i just came up with a solution, what if i just make a global static class Entities that holds all the vector of entities in the scene. Every entity could have access to this class and when a entity is created it just adds a pointer version of itself to the corresponding vector(s) in that global class.

EDIT 2: But i forgot that my solution requires me to still manually add every entity to its matching vector. I just split the work among the different entities.

Comment: You could just only add it to `sprites` and just figure out if it's a `MoveableObject` by querying some member variable.

Comment: Have a means to access those lists (for instance each component would have a static vector of all its instances) and sign up to proper lists in a constructor of particular component. Althought I don't recommend that approach. Rather go with factories that do all necessary logic that requires tracking/registering of components.

Comment: Why not use virtual functions and polymorphism instead? Then you only need one collection of your objects.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i am using that. But i need to call different functions depending on what category the object belongs to. For all movableObjects i want to update the position while for all fixedObjects i might want to do something else. For all CollisionObjects i want to check collision / update the collisionBox etc...

Comment: @GillBates thanks for the anwer but how i design the engine i already know what child object should belong in what vector. I just need the means to do it, but i think i have a solution similar to what Adrian Lis suggested.

Comment: @Bonbin I would tackle the problem from a different angle. I think you might be misusing inheritance. I would try to solve this in another way and using composition. 

First of all MovableObject and FixedObject do not have to be sprites. For example what if you want to add audio emitters at a later stage. You  want to have static audio sources which position you dont update and MovableObjects for movable audio. What then? Will you inherit from those ? But they have a base of sprite. Think about that ;)

Comment: @AdrianLis Thanks for the input but this was just and example to be honest. My actual hirarchy has Entity as its base :P. Also my teachers does not allow me to use anything but inheritance :/

Comment: Ah so its an assignment. Ok then. Nevermind my answer.

Comment: @Bonbin: Your teachers then apparently do not understand the benefits and drawbacks of inheritance, which is sad. It should be widely known since 1994 that huge inheritance trees suck, because that's when the seminal "Design Patterns" was published and explained that one should favour object composition over class inheritance.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I dont think my university educates me in the inheritance design pattern because it is the "best" but because its very widely used and easy to grasp for noobs, this course is taken early in the education.

Comment: @Bonbin: There are plenty of actual use cases for inheritance which don't teach bad habits to noobs. Heck, even the Design Patterns book itself uses inheritance in every pattern. But "my teachers does not allow me to use anything but inheritance" is utter nonsense.

Comment: @ChristianHackl i might have exaggerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice problem.

I think that I would implement it like this: There will be an `addToVector()` method in `Sprite` class, and each derived class will override it to add itself to the corresponding vector.

Comment: Simple and nice solution, I will just add a comment. It might be tempting to add the call to addToVector() in the constructor of those derived classes but this is not exactly safe to call virtual functions in constructors and may lead to undefined behavior. Having a dedicated factory function that will create an object and then call the addToVector on an instance seems like a good solution so the user doesn't forget to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach. But before I start I would like to note one thing with your current design.

I would hide the creation of those objects behind a facade. Call it a scene or whatever. Using `new` manually is bad from a couple of perspectives. First of all if you decide you want to change the scheme on how you allocate/construct your objects you have to change it everywhere in the code. If you have a lets say a factory like `Scene` you just change the implementation and the calls to `scene->CreateObject<Sprite>()` will remain the same everywhere else. This might get important once you start adding stuff like custom memory allocation schemes, object pools etc and at some point you will if you will start to grow your engine. Even if this is just an excercise and a for fun project we all want to do this like its actually done, right ;) ?

Now going back to the core - dont abuse inheritance.

MovableObject is not a Sprite. Static Object is not a sprite either. They are that, movable and static elements.

A sprite can be movable or static, so it has a behavior of a dynamic or static element.

Use composition instead. Make a Sprite accepting behavior, or better a list of behaviors. In fact the Sprite itself is just a behavior on a Game object too, it just controls the way it is presented to the user.

What if you had an object that can be attached multiple behaviors like the fact it is a dynamic one, it has a sprite presence on the scene and even more is a sound emitter!

If you add those behaviors to the object you have to create them first. They can, when constructed, decide to which list they should subscribe to.

This is all metaphors for actually a well known system, that is proven to work well and is actually used in most game engines nowadays. Its a Entity Component System.

You object with behaviors are Entities, Components are those Behaviors and each of them is controlled by one system that knows the component and knows how to update/handle them.

Objects in the scene are merely a set of components attached to them that act upon them.

Comment: I was actually planning on using something called templates that would allow me to Apply a behaviour (like collision) to multiple objects. But as i mentioned in the comment this is a school project with very strict guidlines which specify that i need to use inheritance so the current approach needs to stay. My question has been answered already but ill give you +1 for a very informative post and i will probably look in to the design pattern you are decribing in future projects :)